# Input not writing into input field.. Issue caused by React useForm Hook register validations

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

```js
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, setValue } = useForm();
<div className="col pl-0 pr-3">
   <FormInput
      id="id"
      name="name"
      isAllowed={e => e.value == '' || (e.value.length <= 14 && e.floatValue >= 0)}
      allowLeadingZeros={true}
      decimalScale={0}
      onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      value={Name}
      ref={register({ required: { value: true, message: "Please enter name" } })}
    />
   <ErrorMessage
      errors={errors}
      className="col-md-6"
      name="name"
      as="small"
    />
</div>
```

In above mentioned code,, here FormInput is customized from StyledInput.

After displaying invalid message, when I am trying to enter something in input field, first character is not writing in field but it is clearing invalid error message from second character writing into field. What's the problem How to solve it Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

By using control input, 3rd party library can work with react-hook-form.
https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs

```js
<Controller
    as={
       <NumberFormat
           thousandSeparator={true}
           allowLeadingZeros={true}
           decimalScale={0}
           onValueChange={(value) => {
             console.log(value);
           }}
           isAllowed={(e) =>
             e.value === "" || (e.value.length <= 14 && e.floatValue >= 0)
           }
       />
   }
   id="id"
   name="name"
   defaultValue="1234"
   control={control}
   rules={{
      required: true,
      minLength: 2
   }}
/>
```

---

There is no need to use another state to control the value.
The component is register in react-hooks-form with name "name", it will create the name state and handled state change for you.

Remove the following lines:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState(); // I think you have your own name state, remove it
value={name} // remove it
onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} // remove it
```

Comment: In one case, need to fill data into name field So here I used state

Comment: what is the state used for? i created a codesandbox, can you try to simulate your flow there so I know what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-wilbur-ld104?file=/src/App.js

Comment: when you edit the codesandbox, it will create a new fork. share the link so i can see it after you update the code

Comment: you can use `setValue` to fill data into name field, see the updated code in codesandbox

Comment: Ok, I removed value and onChange...but still issue remains same.

Comment: how to set value for name with ```setValue```` <-- read the code in codesandbox link , it is already there. `setValue("name", "123", { shouldValidate: true, shouldDirty: true });`

Comment: If I remove default value "123" and if it is empty...,,error message displaying initially...how to avoid this?

Comment: you can set `shouldValidate: false` and `shouldDirty: false`

Comment: Yes...In that case...My issue reproduced

Comment: @VenkatReddy Can you share it in codesandbox?

Comment: Can you give the code sample for <NumberFormat/> in place of  <input/> tag which is imported from 'react-number-format'.

Comment: updated the codesandbox. no issue at all.

Comment: Thank You. It solves my problem. But one more thing is How to give error messages differently for multiple validations. For same input field, for required 'It Is required ' and for minLength 'Min length must be 10 digits' like this.

Comment: updated codesandbox. just a example of it. you can make it more generic.

Comment: According to the react-number-format doc. onChange no longer gets values object. You need to use onValueChange instead. onChange/onFocus/onBlur and other input events will be directly passed to the input. So what are you using onChange for?

Comment: onChange is for to set value and read it from entire component...

Comment: use onValueChange then.

Comment: I understand you are new in stackoverflow but next time, please prepare a minimal example for other to help you. It is not my job to simulate your case.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes..I am new to stackoverflow. And last I need is onBlur event.

Comment: updated codesandbox. If you need full control of onXXX event. you can use `render` instead of `as`.

Comment: Please upvote as well (the up arrow) if you find it useful. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments

Comment: If name field is invalid...when I click on button...screen not moving  up to Name field..How to do this ?   Screen simply waiting at button which is not user friendly.

Comment: It is totally a different question. It is not related to the topic at all. The stated problem is solved. I don't mind if you revoked this accepted answer. I am not here to earn points.
I think you are not aware your own problem. I read your profile and there were comments tell you how to ask questions and post the code in 2020 already! Please respect the community and their effort.

Comment: My actual problem is solved but by this code new issue is produced. With my previous code, displaying invalid message and screen moving up to invalid field. But with this code my issue is solved but screen not moving up. that's why I posted here about this issue.

Comment: No one know how your previous code works and it is not react-hook-form responsibility on moving up/down the screen to invalid field.

Comment: I stop here. The message is too long and hope someone can help you.